# Undefined control sequence error with laTex beamer

Tags: beamer, errors

I'm having trouble working with this code

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass[handout,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\batchmode
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate,epsfig,bbm,calc,color,ifthen,capt-of}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{senac}

%-------------------------Titulo/Autores/Orientador------------------------------------------------
\title[IGTDT Centre]{Activities}
\subtitle{ Meeting}
\institute[]{\large IGTDT Centre \\ GYUHJUYT}
\date{27th June - 2017}
\author[ Meeting]{JACK katil}

%-------------------------Logo na parte de baixo do slide------------------------------------------
%\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.7cm]{iccsir_logo3}{iccsir_logo3}
%\logo{\pgfuseimage{iccsir_logo3}\hspace*{0.5cm}}

%-------------------------Este código faz o menuzinho bacana na parte superior do slide------------
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

%---Gerador de Sumário---------------------------------------------------------
\frame{\titlepage}
\section[]{}
\begin{frame}{Contents}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%---Fim do Sumário------------------------------------------------------------


% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Past Years’ activities}
\begin{frame}{Past 5 Years’ activities}
\begin{itemize}
    \item  Dipole and sea salinity

    \item  rainfall over  region
    \item Satellite data of cloud –  climatology    
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}{Next Years’ activities}
\begin{itemize}
    \item  change mitigation

    \item Study of ground water over 

    \item Building 

    \item Weather 

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{SWOT}
\begin{frame}{SWOT Ana}
\begin{column}{1\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{SWOT}
\end{column}
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{El Niño-2017}
\begin{frame}{El Niño Condition}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10cm, height=5cm]{Elnino-2017}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Normal conditions are present.

    \item Equatorial sea surface temperatures (SSTs) are near-to average in the central and east-central Pacific Ocean. 

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}[c]{El Niño Condition}
\centering
\vspace{3}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Elnino-2017A}
\begin{itemize}
    \vspace{3}
    \item In absence of El Nino, the Southwest Monsoon 2017 is expected to be NORMAL.

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Seasonal Monsoon Forecast}
\begin{frame}{Seasonal Monsoon Forecast-USA Model}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
        \begin{column}{.54\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{SW-MONSOON-USA1}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Part of normal rainfall
                \item During later possible.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Seasonal Monsoon}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{SW-MONSOON}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.43\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item The rainfall during summer 
            \item Part of  normal rainfall.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{South America Rainfall}

    \begin{frame}{South America Rainfall }
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
        \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Monsoon-Brazil}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
                \item\justifying Brazil : In their June Crop Report
                \item Sorghum and rice  practically unchanged.

            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}{South America (Brazil and Argentina) : Rainfall}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Monsoon-Brazil1}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
            \item\justifying Wheat production  more with a projected production of 31.5 million tons. 

        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \section{}
 \begin{frame}[c]
 \centering

 \textbf{\large Thank You for the attention}\\
   \vspace*{1cm}     
    Suggestions for providing additional services /informations are most welcome 

\end{frame}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Monsoon Rainfall-2017}
\begin{frame}{Cumulative Rainfall as on 25th June, 2017}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{MONSOON}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Country =  - 1 \% 
            \item Ka \& So region : Rainfall = - 52 \% 
            \item Kon \& region: Rai= - 3 \% 
            \item Marfall = + 47 \%
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}


% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{District wise Cumulative Rainfall}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{SW-MONSOON-CUMULATIVE-IMD3B}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item\justifying Centralred zones).

            \item\justifying The exd normal rainfall (Green and blue zones). 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}{District wise Cumulative Rainfall}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{SW-MONSOON}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item\justifying Most part of the
            \vspace{3} 
            \item\justifying   some part ofrainfall (Red zones). 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

%-----------------------------------------------Este comentario nunca aparecera
```

Error massgae:

```
line 82: Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}
line 82: Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}
line 82: Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}
line 82: Package keyval Error: undefined. \end{frame}
line 82: Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}
line 82: Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}
line 82: Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}
line 106: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{frame}
line 106: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{frame}
line 137: File `SW-MONSOON' not found. \end{frame}
line 207: File `MONSOON' not found. \end{frame}
line 242: File `SW-MONSOON' not found. \end{frame}
line 242: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{frame}
line 95: Overfull \vbox (0.40567pt too high) detected
line 123: Overfull \hbox (3.0712pt too wide) detected
line 137: Overfull \hbox (9.2183pt too wide) detected
```

Comment: Without a pointer for the color theme, it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whatever editor you use, use another one that shows you the whole error message an not just the first line. This would have told you where the problems in your code are.

Two main problems

- you cannot use a `column` outside a `columns` environment
- you cannot use `\vspace{3}` without a unit, e.g. it should be `\vspace{3pt}` or whatever unit you had in mind when choosing `3`

Other comments:

- You don't need

  `\usepackage{graphicx}, \usepackage{etoolbox}, \usepackage{enumerate}, \usepackage{color}`

  Beamer loads all these packages for you
- I don't have `\usecolortheme{senac}`. If this causes a problem, include a link where to find this file
- only specify either the width or the height of an image, not both, this will distort the image in 99.9999 % of the cases.
- most of your columns are too big, e.g. if you combine `\begin{column}{.54\textwidth}` and `\begin{column}{.47\textwidth}` this cannot fit on a frame without going into the margin
- Why do you have `\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}` inside of itemize environments?

---

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass[handout,t]{beamer}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\batchmode
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{epsfig,bbm,calc}
%\usepackage{color
\usepackage{ifthen,capt-of}
\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usecolortheme{senac}

%-------------------------Titulo/Autores/Orientador------------------------------------------------
\title[IGTDT Centre]{Activities}
\subtitle{Meeting}
\institute[]{\large IGTDT Centre \\ GYUHJUYT}
\date{27th June - 2017}
\author[ Meeting]{JACK katil}

%-------------------------Logo na parte de baixo do slide------------------------------------------
%\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.7cm]{iccsir_logo3}{iccsir_logo3}
%\logo{\pgfuseimage{iccsir_logo3}\hspace*{0.5cm}}

%-------------------------Este código faz o menuzinho bacana na parte superior do slide------------
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

%---Gerador de Sumário---------------------------------------------------------
\frame{\titlepage}
\section[]{}
\begin{frame}{Contents}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%---Fim do Sumário------------------------------------------------------------


% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Past Years’ activities}
\begin{frame}{Past 5 Years’ activities}
\begin{itemize}
    \item  Dipole and sea salinity
    \item  rainfall over  region
    \item Satellite data of cloud –  climatology    
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}{Next Years’ activities}
\begin{itemize}
    \item change mitigation
    \item Study of ground water over 
    \item Building 
    \item Weather 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{SWOT}
\begin{frame}{SWOT Ana}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{1\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{El Niño-2017}
\begin{frame}{El Niño Condition}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10cm, height=5cm]{example-image}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Normal conditions are present.

    \item Equatorial sea surface temperatures (SSTs) are near-to average in the central and east-central Pacific Ocean. 

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}[c]{El Niño Condition}
\centering
\vspace{3pt}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\begin{itemize}
    \vspace{3pt}
    \item In absence of El Nino, the Southwest Monsoon 2017 is expected to be NORMAL.

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Seasonal Monsoon Forecast}
\begin{frame}{Seasonal Monsoon Forecast-USA Model}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
        \begin{column}{.54\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Part of normal rainfall
                \item During later possible.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Seasonal Monsoon}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.43\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item The rainfall during summer 
            \item Part of  normal rainfall.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{South America Rainfall}

    \begin{frame}{South America Rainfall }
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
        \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
                \item\justifying Brazil : In their June Crop Report
                \item Sorghum and rice  practically unchanged.

            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}{South America (Brazil and Argentina) : Rainfall}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
            \item\justifying Wheat production  more with a projected production of 31.5 million tons. 

        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \section{}
 \begin{frame}[c]
 \centering

 \textbf{\large Thank You for the attention}\\
   \vspace*{1cm}     
    Suggestions for providing additional services /informations are most welcome 

\end{frame}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Monsoon Rainfall-2017}
\begin{frame}{Cumulative Rainfall as on 25th June, 2017}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Country =  - 1 \% 
            \item Ka \& So region : Rainfall = - 52 \% 
            \item Kon \& region: Rai= - 3 \% 
            \item Marfall = + 47 \%
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}


% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{District wise Cumulative Rainfall}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item\justifying Centralred zones).

            \item\justifying The exd normal rainfall (Green and blue zones). 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}{District wise Cumulative Rainfall}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item\justifying Most part of the
            \vspace{3pt} 
            \item\justifying   some part ofrainfall (Red zones). 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

%-----------------------------------------------Este comentario nunca aparecera
```

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the \batchmode command. You want to take care of LaTeX errors as soon as they appear.
- Your document works fine with a current version of TeXLive and pdflatex if you remove \usecolortheme{senac} command (and \usepackage[brazil]{babel} - I did not have the corresponding files). So your problems may stem from the color theme file.

Comment: I have removed the \batchmode command and problem still the same.
\usecolortheme{senac} i have defined for the presentation color, i have that file inside the folder. I don't think problem with color file.

Comment: @SWAT Did you try commenting out the color scheme inclusion line? "\end{frame}" being undefined is a pretty weird error. The way to debug it is to remove as much as possible from your file until the error disappears.

Comment: As already written, with the files available to the reader of this site, your document seems to be almost fine (if you remove the includegraphics lines -- we do not have the images) -- after adding units to the \vspace{...} commands.

Comment: @SWAT If you don't think the problem is in the colour file, why did you include it in the example code you posted in your answer???